# How to validate an Input Array field in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

How can I write rule for input field like below:

```
{!! Form::number("amount[]",null,['min' => 0, 'class' => 'form-control col-xs-2 ']) !!}
```

I tried following which gave error: `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

```
        $rules = array(
            'amount[]' => 'required'
        );
        $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Update:

I tried this as suggested by a user, it's not redirecting it on page again. Below is controller method:

```
public function postEstimate(Request $request) {
        $rules = array(
            'amount' => 'required|array'
        );

        $this->validate($request, $rules);
    }
```

Comment: You get this error because it consider `amount[]` as array,cant you call the field `amount`?

Comment: @Gal if you meant in `rules` then yes I already set it as `amount` but it's not catching it at all.

Comment: I meant both,form & rules,if you don't want to change that you could call it as `amount.0` inside rules (in case this is your first amount[]) but I don't see why you would want to do it like this.

Comment: @Gal fields are Dynamic,  not pre-defined.

Comment: I see,this might help you out - [How to validate array input?](http://laravel.io/forum/11-12-2014-how-to-validate-array-input#reply-21935) its not exactly the same as you dont need `valueKey` all you need to do is iterate once just to build the array of rules for your `amount` array. if you dont have an option to delete the dynamic fields you might be able to use `range` function from 0 to array length.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you got issues with what I explained so this is what I meant -

```
$rules = [];
$count_amounts = count($request->input('amount'));
foreach (range(0, $count_amounts) as $number) {
    $rules['amount.' . $number] = 'required|integer|min:0';
}
```

This should check that each `amount` input you have is an integer and is bigger than `0` (like you defined in the html validation)

Answer (score 1):

Instead try this:

```
private  $rules = array(
            'amount' => 'required|array',
        );

public function postEstimate(Request $request) {


        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
    }
```

or, try a validation with a `'amount' => 'required`

im not sure about this `'amount' => 'required|array`

Comment: By using `amount` only it's not detecting field at all. `array` rule introduced in Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 1):

**For custom rules implementation of integer type value check of an array**

firstly open the following file

```
/resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

Then add the custom message

```
'numericarray'         => 'The :attribute must be numeric array value.',
'requiredarray'        => 'The :attribute must required all element.',
```

Again open the another file

```
/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
```

Now add custom validation code in the boot function.

```
public function boot()
{

    $this->app['validator']->extend('numericarray', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            if (!is_int($v)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });

   $this->app['validator']->extend('requiredarray', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            if(empty($v)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });

}
```

Now you can use the **requiredarray**  for all element required of array. And also use the **numericarray** for integer type value check of array

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'field_name1' => 'requiredarray',
            'field_name2' => 'numericarray'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you expect `amount` as an array the rules should be

```
$rules = array(
    'amount' => 'required|array'
);
```

check the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-array)

If your not redirecting or getting a validation error means there is no validation error

just `dd($request->input('amount'))` in the controller and check its a `array` or not if it's a array then validations will pass.

Comment: It's not validating it at all.

Comment: The rule `required|array` still does not work as of 5.3.